# What is re.sub in graphviz.Source()

Tags: python, regex, graphviz

I am trying to use this function called `draw_tree`.

```
def draw_tree(t, df, size=10, ratio=0.6, precision=0):
    """ Draws a representation of a random forest in IPython.
    Parameters:
    -----------
    t: The tree you wish to draw
    df: The data used to train the tree. This is used to get the names of the features.
    """
    s=export_graphviz(t, out_file=None, feature_names=df.columns, filled=True,
                      special_characters=True, rotate=True, precision=precision)
    IPython.display.display(graphviz.Source(re.sub('Tree {',
            f'Tree {{ size={size}; ratio={ratio}', s)))
```

However when I use it in my program, I get an error:

> NameError: name 're' is not defined

Here is the call to the function

```
draw_tree(m.estimators_[0],df,precision=3)
```

I am unsure what this `re` object is meant to be. I am aware that the `graphviz` library has changed quite a bit between versions, so perhaps I am not using the correct version or prehaps I'm missing a required module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `import re` should solve the issue.

This is a module where regular expressions can be applied, see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

[re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) will change the string argument of `graphviz.Source` according to `s` in your case.

You're calling `graphviz.Source` via `IPython.display.display` method as an argument. So `re` is indeed a top-level module you have to import first to get this working. This has nothing to do with `graphviz` library, because you're first make some substitutions to the string which will be an argument for the `graphviz` library. And the substitution will be evaluated first, before calling any `graphviz` sources or `Ipython` sources.

The solution is then to add `import re` **before** calling `graphviz.Source` with the `re.sub(…)` method inside. *(Importing re in the same function or in the module, doesn't matter.)*

It should also be mentioned that your code snippet where the replacement is defined, seems not to work. After resolving your issue with the `re` library, you have to bugfix your replacement regex. I've already linked the method `re.sub` for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub('Tree {',f'Tree {{ size={size}; ratio={ratio}', s)
```

This is replacing with regex (enhanced `str.replace()`). So you need to add `re` module to perform this function.

```
import re
```